# How to test for 'if arcpy.exists' with RemoveFeatureClassFromTopology stand-alone script?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, topology, versioning, error-999999

I have some dataset topologies that I want to loop through, but I need to test for the assignment of feature classes so the scripts don't fail. (Using Win 7, ArcGIS 10.2, Python 2.7.5 and a file GDB)

My research hasn't turned up too much but using the 10.2 "Remove Feature Class From Topology (Data Management)", using ArcCatalog I can remove an existing fc from the topo set. If however I run the script 'stand alone' and the fc isn't currently assigned to the topology, the script fails. (Error shown below script)

I read this post ([ArcMap remove feature-class from feature-dataset](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126355/arcmap-remove-feature-class-from-feature-dataset)) as well but I don't want to delete the fc, I only want to remove it from the topo if it exists as I need it again later.

Am I going down the wrong path?

```
Using ArcCatalog, this succeeds if the fc exists;
topo = "C:/Data/Terrain_36/TOPO_EXPORT_2015_09_09_1_2.gdb/ZONES_1_2/TOPO_1_2"
fc = "RL_10"
arcpy.RemoveFeatureClassFromTopology_management(topo, fc)

# Running the script below as 'stand alone', fails if the fc isnt currently assigned;
# import modules
import arcpy, sys, os, datetime, traceback, string, time
from os import sep, listdir
from arcpy import env  as env

# This scripts name
script_name = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
# Create file prefix for unique file naming
prefix = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H%M')
# Create file suffix for avoiding filenames staring with numbers
suffix = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H%M')

# Set variables
Top_Dir = "C:/Data/Terrain_36"
td = Top_Dir
print "Top_Dir set to: '" +td+ "'" + '\n'
# Out_Dir = td+sep+ 'Exports'
# print "Out_Dir set to: '" +Out_Dir+ "'" + '\n'
Log_Dir = td+sep+ 'zz_logs'
print "Log_Dir set to: '" +Log_Dir+ "'" + '\n'
GDB_Nam = 'TOPO_EXPORT_2015_09_09_1_2.gdb'
print "GDB_Nam set to: '" +GDB_Nam+ "'" + '\n'
GDB_Home = os.path.join(td, GDB_Nam)
print  "GDB_Home set to: '" +GDB_Home+ "'" + '\n'

# Set the workspace environment
env.workspace = os.path.join(Top_Dir, GDB_Nam)
ws = env.workspace
print "Env.workspace set to: '" +ws+ "'" '\n'
topo = "C:/Data/Terrain_36/TOPO_EXPORT_2015_09_09_1_2.gdb/ZONES_1_2/TOPO_1_2"
fc = "RL_10"
if arcpy.Exists (fc):
    arcpy.RemoveFeatureClassFromTopology_management(topo, fc)

# My error messages
Log: 2015-09-14 11:48:32.722000
Begin process: Topo_script.py
 Process started at 2015-09-14 11:48:32.722000
 PYTHON ERRORS:
 Traceback info:
   File "C:\Data\Terrain_36\Data_quality\_Scripts\Topo_script.py", line 62, in <module> arcpy.RemoveFeatureClassFromTopology_management(topo, fc)
 ArcPy ERRORS:
 ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
 Cannot register as versioned on this database.
 Cannot register as versioned on this database.
 Failed to execute (RemoveFeatureClassFromTopology).
```

Comment: To be part of a topology the feature class should be in a feature dataset, your value topo isn't a feature dataset... Can you insert a screen shot of your full path to topology and feature classes in catalog please.

Comment: Yes, it is in fact part of a feature dataset. Unfortuantely I cant do screen shot stuff at work (Gov dept) but have updated the path above.

Comment: Your workspace isn't set. arcpy.env.workspace = r"c:\Data\Terrain_36\TOPO_EXPORT_2015_09_09_1_2.gdb\ZONES_1_2" as you're using the short name arcpy can't find it. Either use the full path to the feature class or set your workspace prior.

Comment: Yes, it is in fact set earlier within a much larger script. Unfortunately it will only further confuse things if I post the entire code but I will add it to my snippet above for completeness. It isnt why it doesnt run but I do appreciate your input.

Comment: I can see there's more lines as the error occurs on line 62... the error is about versioning, not about arcpy.Exists, is this a checkout version (replica)? Your workspace isn't quite right, you (might) need the feature dataset in there as well... geodatabases can be a bit funny like that. env.workspace = os.path.join(Top_Dir, GDB_Nam, "TOPO_1_2") try that and see if it helps.

Comment: It is a gdb copy of an Oracle sde database wihich has been unregistered from versioning. My puzzle comes about that i can easily 'remove the feature class' through ArcCatalog using the toolbox and also as stand alone arcpy script. It crashes out (and correclt I suspect) if the fc does not exists and thats why Im trying to test for it. I hope this explains better.

Comment: Yes, it's one of those funny things in a database/feature dataset. Exists returns true if the feature class is in the database *somewhere*, either standalone or in a feature dataset, but to correctly locate the feature class you need to include the feature dataset in the path. Sometimes you can get away without it but a lot of the time you can't...

Comment: Ok thanks. I will add the feature datasset to the path and give that a try.

Comment: No good unfortunately, same result as before. When I run as stand alone without the 'if exists' it runs fine and I am comfortable the database/feature dataset is seen correctly. (Mind you it had been a callenge originally when the dataset and featureclass had the same name in sde)

Comment: That could be confusing the Exists function.. in ArcObjects I would use IWorkspace2.NameExists function and use esriDatasetType of feature class of esriDTFeatureClass but the arcpy.Exists says yes if anything exists with that name... names are supposed to be unique in the database so your feature dataset and feature class should not have the same name.. does your feature class have an alias name?

Comment: No the duplicate is in the original sde. I have renamed the feature class in the GDB to avoid this issue and it is now unique..

Comment: If it's part of a topology you can't rename it until it's unlinked. From what I've seen of your code it should be working, I think it's time to get Esri support to have a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use `arcpy.Describe` on the topology itself and see if the featureclass is in the [`featureClassNames`](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/Topology_properties/018v00000054000000/) attribute?

Something simple like:

```
if fc in arcpy.Describe(topo).featureClassNames:
    arcpy.RemoveFeatureClassFromTopology_management(topo, fc)
else:
    print "{0} wasn't in the topology...".format(fc)
```

Comment: Absolutely fabulous thanks @Evil-genius. That achieves my goal precisely and was an option I had not thought of.